# Paypal Adaptive Payments Sales Tax

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

Using Paypal's Adaptive Payments API, I am selling physical items that require a ship to address - on the Paypal purchase page I inform Paypal to have the customer select an address. If I have sales tax rules set up on my merchant account, how do I get Adaptive Payments to add sales tax to the order - I hand it the subtotal, and based on the state in the address the user selects, it calculates and adds the sales tax to that subtotal for a grand total?

Isn't this the entire point of Paypal - customer provides this information to Paypal, and then provides me only the information I need for the transaction?

Comment: I'd like to have a reason for the vote to close this question. If it's duplicate, I'd obviously like to see the answer to that one - but a quick Google search does not answer this question, hence why it's here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't seem to be able to compute this on its own - I ended up keeping a hack of a solution in place. Prompt the user to provide the state to which the goods will be shipped to, and then calculate the tax on my own before sending the order total (subtotal + tax) to the Paypal workflow. Disappointing, IMO.

Answer (score 3):

You're right but AFAIK, since PayPal does not want to keep tax rates which differ for countries and type of goods you ship. So, you can either try using

```
GetShippingAddresses
```

api call before executing the payment, and add

```
totalTax
```

information during

```
SetPaymentsOptions
```

call..

Comment: I understand that I could charge a flat tax rate, but if I charge different tax rates dependent on where the goods are being shipped to, I wouldn't be able to do this because I don't know the customer's address (nor should I). In order to do this (we already do for other type of purchases) I'd have to ask the customer what state the goods are being shipped to BEFORE Paypal opens - which is against the spirit of what Paypal does.